# Inconsistent Graph Ordering when using Flet library in Python

Tags: python, flet

I am using the Flet library in Python to draw multiple graphs. The code runs without any issues, but the order in which the graphs are displayed changes every time I execute the script. This is not the behavior I was expecting; I would like the graphs to be displayed in a fixed order.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import flet as ft
from flet.matplotlib_chart import MatplotlibChart


def generate_data(data, factor1, factor2):
    return {
        "data": data,
        "AVE": [x * factor1 for x in data],
        "MAX": [x * factor2 for x in data],
        "MIN": [x * factor2 for x in data],
    }


def plot_graph(df, ax, title):
    ax.plot(df["data"], df["AVE"], label="AVE", marker="o")
    ax.plot(df["data"], df["MAX"], label="MAX", marker="x")
    ax.set_title(title)


def create_data_table(data_array, columns):
    row_data = list(zip(*[data_array[col] for col in columns]))
    return [
        ft.DataRow(cells=[ft.DataCell(ft.Text(str(cell))) for cell in row])
        for row in row_data
    ]


def main(page: ft.Page):
    columns = ["data", "AVE", "MAX", "MIN"]
    data = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

    data_sets = [generate_data(data, i, i + 1) for i in range(1, 4)]
    dfs = [pd.DataFrame(data_set) for data_set in data_sets]
    figs, axs = zip(*[plt.subplots() for _ in data_sets])

    for df, ax, title in zip(dfs, axs, ["fig1", "fig2", "fig3"]):
        plot_graph(df, ax, title)

    table_columns = [ft.DataColumn(ft.Text(name)) for name in columns]
    data_tables = [create_data_table(data_set, columns) for data_set in data_sets]

    row_graphs = ft.Row(controls={MatplotlibChart(fig, expand=True) for fig in figs})

    row_tables = ft.Row(
        controls={
            ft.DataTable(
                columns=table_columns,
                rows=rows,
            )
            for rows in data_tables
        }
    )

    page.add(row_graphs)
    page.add(row_tables)


ft.app(target=main)
```

I am drawing different graphs (fig1, fig2, fig3) for each dataset, and these graphs are displayed in a random order.

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Feel free to paste your code into this template and post your question. If anyone knows how to solve this problem, your input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough experience with Flet. I think the reason for the irregular order is that the lines are specified in dictionary form. Changing it to a list would put them in the same position.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import flet as ft
from flet.matplotlib_chart import MatplotlibChart


def generate_data(data, factor1, factor2):
    return {
        "data": data,
        "AVE": [x * factor1 for x in data],
        "MAX": [x * factor2 for x in data],
        "MIN": [x * factor2 for x in data],
    }


def plot_graph(df, ax, title):
    print(title)
    ax.plot(df["data"], df["AVE"], label="AVE", marker="o")
    ax.plot(df["data"], df["MAX"], label="MAX", marker="x")
    ax.set_title(title)


def create_data_table(data_array, columns):
    row_data = list(zip(*[data_array[col] for col in columns]))
    return [
        ft.DataRow(cells=[ft.DataCell(ft.Text(str(cell))) for cell in row])
        for row in row_data
    ]


def main(page: ft.Page):
    columns = ["data", "AVE", "MAX", "MIN"]
    data = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

    data_sets = [generate_data(data, i, i + 1) for i in range(1, 4)]
    dfs = [pd.DataFrame(data_set) for data_set in data_sets]
    #figs, axs = zip(*[plt.subplots(i) for i,_ in enumerate(data_sets,start=1)])
    figs, axs = zip(*[plt.subplots() for _ in data_sets])
    
    for df, ax, title in zip(dfs, axs, ["fig1", "fig2", "fig3"]):
        plot_graph(df, ax, title)

    table_columns = [ft.DataColumn(ft.Text(name)) for name in columns]
    data_tables = [create_data_table(data_set, columns) for data_set in data_sets]
    # dict -> list
    row_graphs = ft.Row(controls=[MatplotlibChart(fig, expand=True) for fig in figs])
    # dict -> list
    row_tables = ft.Row(
        controls=[
            ft.DataTable(
                columns=table_columns,
                rows=rows,
            )
            for rows in data_tables
        ]
    )
    
    page.add(row_graphs)
    page.add(row_tables)
```